# missing link between urdf and rosserial

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have an arexx robot arm: http://www.arexx.com/robot_arm/
Following a tutorial, I created an urdf file for my robot arm.
Then I followed the tutorial for the "Planning Description Configuration Wizard". It does the path planning and IK in the simulator nicely.
On the other hand, I followed the rosserial Arduino stuff to make the hardware interface. But I'm missing the link between the two.
My code so far is in : https://github.com/ulrichard/robotloader/tree/master/ros
What is the usual practice to connect from the urdf to the physical robot using rosserial?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12991/missing-link-between-urdf-and-rosserial/) by [ulrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1774/ulrichard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-02-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using a URDF you will need to publish joint states from the hardware(aka that's what needs to come from your rosserial devices. And then a tool like [robot_state_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_state_publisher) can help to make it work with the URDF.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-08**:
If you just have open loop there's not need to send data through the rosserial process.  Just estimate the movement and publish in a simple node based on the commands.